# Firefox not launching after installing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: firefox, permissions, sudo, virtualenvwrapper

I attempted installing virtualenvwrapper yesterday. Part of the install process required me to install virtualenvwrapper by using

```
sudo pip install ...
```

regardless of the warning the system gives. This was as per the installation documentation.

Now, I cannot open Firefox at all. It just refuses to launch. I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it twice now. Rebooted countless times, but still. When attempting to remove virtualenvwrapper via the terminal, I get the following error:

```
enzosnyman@Enzos-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
WARNING: The directory '/Users/enzosnyman/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Found existing installation: virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4
Uninstalling virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11-nspkg.pth
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11.egg-info
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/project.py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/user_scripts.py
Proceed (Y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11.egg-info' -> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/~irtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11.egg-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 105, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 664, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 373, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 271, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 312, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 838, in move
    raise PermissionError("Cannot move the non-empty directory "
PermissionError: Cannot move the non-empty directory '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11.egg-info': Lacking write permission to '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py3.11.egg-info'.
```